# Cannot update variable from function within event handler unless its declared globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, scope, socket.io

I have a nodejs backend app that utilizes mongoose for db connections and queries which, in this case, executes in an event handler of socket.io, namely
`io.on("connection", [callback])`

However, whenever I run a query inside an event handler of `io.on("connection")`, like `socket.on("myEvent", [callback])` I have trouble updating a variable within that latter event handler - specifically, when its the callback of a mongoose query.

For some context, heres and example of what im trying to run:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  var myVar; // declare user within event handler scope
  socket.on("myEvent", function(m) {
    var query = m.myQuery;
    User.findOne({query}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      // error handling
    } else {
      myVar = doc;
      console.log(myVar); // logs whole document as it should
    }
  });

  socket.on("myOtherEvent", function(m){
    console.log(myVar); // undefined!?
  });
});
```

I've also tried approaching this issue using a custom callback on an own function which runs the same query and returns the document since I thought that this might be caused by the db queries being asynchronous - that approach, however, doesn't work either.

Additionally, I've tried using the (apparently infamous) `var that = this` approach in the `socket.on("myEvent)` method in hopes that it would reference to the original callback. No luck on that part either.

Either I have missed the entire point of mongoose or I'm going crazy; Help would be appreciated!

*Edit*: As commented before, as soon as I globally declare `myVar` the variable gets updated in the `else` block of said mongoose query. I then can access it through the other `socket.on` handlers aswell.

Should I declare my variable within the `socket.on("connection")` block it stays the same, e.g. if I `console.log(myVar)` after declaring `myVar = "why isn\'t this working?!"` within `socket.on("myOtherEvent")` it actually logs `"why isn't this working?!"`to the console

*Edit 2*: A very similar problem is described here: [Node, Mongoose - Can't access parent scope in query callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969579/node-mongoose-cant-access-parent-scope-in-query-callback)

The solution of using `myVar = myVar || {}` did, however, not work.

*Edit 3*: As advised, I used (in this case ES6) Promises for my query, my updated query (still inside `socket.on`, just not displayed here) looks like the following example I made based off of it:

```
User.findOne({query}).exec().then(function(doc) {
    if (!doc) {
        myVar = null; // unrelated
        logger.debug("Couldnt find user!"); // unrelated
    } else {
        myVar = doc;
        logger.debug(doc); // correctly prints the whole document
        logger.debug(user); // also correctly prints whole document
    }
}).catch(function(err){
    logger.error("Error searching for query: " + err);// unrelated
});
```

As it stands, should I sometime later try to access `myVar` (after the query has finished and the document was printed to the console, within the `else`-block) it still prints out the initial value I gave to it. Wether be it null, a bool or a string - it remains unchanged.

**But**: The interesting thing to note is that, should I declare it globally, it starts to update the variable - however, it then is not unique to a socket which is why this approach wont work for this specific problem

Comment: In second socket event `myVar` is undefined because some async stuff is happening in first event.
If you need to access data from first event in second event, why you just don't put second event listener in success callback of your query ?
Also you could take look on Generator function or async/await to get rid of callback hell :)

Comment: But when I try to access the variable within the callback, it is defined - this means the code is executed *after* the query was finished, not before, doesn't it?


*Edit: Something that is even weirder is that declaring the var globally actually updates it, like it should. It just doesnt work when I do it within the handler.
Also, thanks for the suggestion with async/await - maybe it'd be really useful to look into it when using something like mongoose* :)

Comment: **1)** How have you deduced that the variable updates properly when declared globally? Do you base this solely from what `console.log(myVar)` produces? If so, this could simply be an 'illusion' caused by the fact that the browser internally defers the actual print-out, resulting in what gets printed is not necessarily the state of the object at the time `console.log` was invoked. In other words, the variable may not have actually been updated as you expected, it just looks that way. Global or local shouldn't make a difference in this case. Try logging with `console.log(typeof myVar)` instead.

Comment: **2)** What triggers the "myOtherEvent" event and how do you make sure it doesn't get triggered until *after* the callback for the `User.findOne` function (which is what updates `myVar`) has been invoked?

Comment: **1)** I have made sure that the variable is updated correctly as I've, when testing, set ```myVar``` to a random string inititally and compared it to the result and data that was passed. In either case, the first log was the string i put in initially, and after the query had executed the whole document was shown. (Note that this is not on the client, but the server-side of things (nodeJs))

Comment: **2)** ```myOtherEvent``` is triggered by a user and rejected if the query has not yet executed, so it could be at any time. I've tried executing it before *and* after the query executed - and it worked as expected, as long as the variable had been delcared globally - which is what makes this issue so weird. As in: should I access it before the query had finished, it wouldve been ```myVar```s initial value - after that, should myOtherEvent be triggered again, it would be the correct document and accessible as it should

Comment: Can you show the client code you used for testing? My guess is a) you were not waiting long enough for the query to finish or b) you actually opened to different connections and received the second event from the other one.

Comment: @Ghost I realized I was incorrectly referring to the browser after I couldn't edit the comment any longer, but what I wrote about `console.log` holds true in Node as well. It's deferred, meaning what it prints out isn't guaranteed to be what the object actually looked like at the time it was passed to `console.log`. However, I think Bergi is on to the real issue here with events by 'cross-triggered', which would explain why it works differently between a scoped variable and a global property.

Comment: This is extremely embressing but Bergi is actually right with multiple socket conenctions being made, which creates multiple instances of socket.io.

Even if by accident I feel like such an idiot for missing something so obvious after going crazy because of hours wasted on this problem.

Ill check if it works and mark it as correct as soon as I've got it working. Thanks for your help, MikaelLennholm and @Bergi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Initially solved by @Bergi - thank you!**

*For any newcomers or people who are unaware (as I have been) that socket connections cannot be merged:*

Specifically related to this problem was that Socket.io creates multiple instances/handlers - one per socket, to be specific. 
This means having multiple socket connections will create multiple instances using said event handlers, which results in multiple instances of these variables too.

This could be quite useful too, if you wanted to - for any reason - have locally scoped variables that are specific to each socket connection, for example.

Thanks!